# I am having an issue with my AI trying to delete the card that it just played?

Tags: c++

I am making a card game, Crazy Eights, I have everything done except I am having a problem with this AI. The AI needs to delete the card it just played from its card options. (Each player is dealt 5 cards, and if the card matches the suit, value, or an 8, it can play). SO far, the computer does play the correct card, it just doesn't remove the card so it can just keep playing and playing.

Main Function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "CCrazyEight.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;


void main()
{
    // Calls Crazy eight and declares a variable, then runs the game
    CCrazyEight E1;
    E1.Menu();
}
```

CCard Header File

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

enum CardSuit { Hearts, Diamonds, Spades, Clubs };

class CCard
{
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &left, CCard right);
private:
    int value;
    CardSuit suit;
public:
    // Constructor, sets default values to suit and value
    CCard()
    {
        value = 1;
        suit = Hearts;
    }
    // return thes value of the card
    int GetValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    // returns the suit of the card
    CardSuit GetSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }
    // Passes values to CDeck constructor, which then randomizes values for the cards
    void InitCard(CardSuit s, int v)
    {
        suit = s;
        if (v > 0 && v < 14)
        {
            value = v;
        }
    }
};
// outputs value and suit of the card
ostream & operator << (ostream &left, CCard right)
{
    if (right.value < 11 && right.value > 1)
    {
        left << right.value;
    }
    else if (right.value == 1)
    {
        left << "Ace";
    }
    else if (right.value == 11)
    {
        left << "Jack";
    }
    else if (right.value == 12)
    {
        left << "Queen";
    }
    else if (right.value == 13)
    {
        left << "King";
    }
    left << " of ";
    if (right.suit == Hearts)
    {
        left << "Hearts";
    }
    else if (right.suit == Diamonds)
    {
        left << "Diamonds";
    }
    else if (right.suit == Spades)
    {
        left << "Spades";
    }
    else if (right.suit == Clubs)
    {
        left << "Clubs";
    }
    return left;
}
```

CDeck Header File

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "CCard.h"
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

class CDeck
{
private:
    CCard Deck[52];
    int TopCard;
public:
    // constructor
    // randomizes the card numbers for suit and value
    CDeck()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        TopCard = 0;
        for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++)
        {
            for (int value = 1; value <= 13; value++)
            {
                Deck[((suit * 13) + value) - 1].InitCard((CardSuit)suit, value);
            }
        }
    }
    // shuffles the deck, completely randomizes the cards
    void Shuffle()
    {
        TopCard = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 52; x++)
            {
                int SwapPosition = rand() % 52;
                CCard temp;
                temp = Deck[x];
                Deck[x] = Deck[SwapPosition];
                Deck[SwapPosition] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    // Draw a card function that gives out a card when called for in crazy eight
    CCard DrawCard()
    {
        if (TopCard > 51)
        {
            cout << "Deck is Empty." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            return Deck[TopCard++];
        }
    }
};
```

CrazyEight header file

```
    #pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "CCard.h"
#include "CDeck.h"
#include "CPlayer.h"
using namespace std;











// Having an issue trying to get the computer to play something different


class CCrazyEight
{
private:
    CDeck d1;
    CCard c1;
    int index;
    CCard Topcard;
    CPlayer Computer;
    CPlayer Human;
public:
    // constructor
    // shuffles the deck to the played, and assigns the topcard to start the game
    CCrazyEight()
    {
        d1.Shuffle();
        c1 = d1.DrawCard();
        Topcard = c1;
    }
    // plays the game, dealing cards to computer and human
    void PlayGame()
    {
        cout << "Welcome to Crazy Eight!" << endl;
        cout << "You get to go first!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            Computer.GetCard(d1.DrawCard());
            Human.GetCard(d1.DrawCard());
        }
    }
    // displays the topmost card
    void TopCard()
    {
        cout << Topcard << endl;
    }
    // displays the cards for the human, and the options they can chose, and anything else they need about the game
    void Menu()
    {
        PlayGame();
        while (Human.NumCards() != 0 || Computer.NumCards() != 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Top Card is: "; TopCard();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "You Have " << Human.NumCards() << " Cards Left." << endl;
            cout << "Your play: " << endl;
            cout << "0) Draw Card" << endl;
            cout << Human << endl;
            cin >> index;
            if (index == 0)
            {
                Human.GetCard(d1.DrawCard());
                Topcard = Topcard;
            }
            else if (index > 0 && index <= Human.NumCards())
            {
                Topcard = Human.CardPlayed(index, Topcard);
            }
            cout << endl;
            Topcard = Computer.ComputerAI(Topcard);
            cout << "Computer Played: " << Topcard << endl;
            if (Computer.NumCards() > 0)
            {
                cout << "Computer has " << Computer.NumCards() << " Cards Left." << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "You Lose!" << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

CPlayer Header File

```
#pragma once
#include "CCard.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CPlayer
{
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &left, CPlayer right);
private:
    CCard Hand[25];
    CDeck d1;
    int NumberOfCard;
    bool Computer;
    const int MaxHand = 26;
    bool TopCard;
public:
    // Constructor for the computer, sets computer to true
    CPlayer(bool computer = true)
    {
        Computer = computer;
        NumberOfCard = 0;
    }
    // Computers AI, checks and sees if they can play, if not then they draw until they can play, or they play a card that is playable******Easy mode**** Lol
    CCard ComputerAI(CCard Topcard)
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCard; i++)
            {
                if (Hand[i].GetSuit() == Topcard.GetSuit() || Hand[i].GetValue() == 8 || Hand[i].GetValue() == Topcard.GetValue())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCard; i++)
                    {
                        if (Topcard.GetSuit() == Hand[i].GetSuit() && Hand[i].GetValue() != 8)
                        {
                            NumberOfCard--;
                            return Hand[i];
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCard; i++)
                    {
                        if (Topcard.GetValue() == Hand[i].GetValue() && Hand[i].GetValue() != 8)
                        {
                            NumberOfCard--;
                            return Hand[i];
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCard; i++)
                    {
                        if (Hand[i].GetValue() == 8)
                        {
                            NumberOfCard--;
                            return Hand[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    GetCard(d1.DrawCard());
                }
            }
    }
    // Is not the computer, sets computer to fasle. i.e. its the human
    void Human()
    {
        Computer = false;
    }
    int NumCards()
    {
        return NumberOfCard;
    }
    // will hand out a card
    bool GetCard(CCard NewCard)
    {
        if (NumberOfCard < MaxHand)
        {
            // Now is taking the card
            Hand[NumberOfCard] = NewCard;
            NumberOfCard++;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    // subtracts the card that was played from the deck of the human user
    CCard CardPlayed(int index, CCard Topcard)
    {
        if (CheckCard(index, Topcard) == true)
        {
            CCard TempTopcard = Hand[index - 1];
            for (int i = index - 1; i <= NumberOfCard - 1; i++)
            {
                Hand[i] = Hand[i + 1];
            }
            NumberOfCard--;
            return TempTopcard;
        }
        else
            cout << "Not a valid Card." << endl;
            return Topcard;
    }
    // checks the card and see's if it is playable or not
    bool CheckCard(int index, CCard Topcard)
    {
        if (Hand[index - 1].GetSuit() == Topcard.GetSuit() || Hand[index - 1].GetValue() == 8 || Hand[index - 1].GetValue() == Topcard.GetValue())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
};
// overloads the output to cout the card
ostream & operator << (ostream &left, CPlayer right)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < right.NumberOfCard; i++)
    {
            left << i + 1 << ") " << right.Hand[i] << endl;
    }
    return left;
}
```

Comment: Check the `ComputerAI` method. You're returning cards but the only _deletion_ is to decrease the number of cards, but in this way you are actually removing the last one.

Comment: Yea, that's what I thought I was doing but I am unsure of how to remove the card that was actually played.